# Checking if a number is in the interval in R

Tags: r

How do I apply a function so it will count the number of times 0 is between the upper and lower bound for both?  I think I should use `findInterval` for Tukey's  but am confused as how to apply.

```
tuke=function(I,J){

  a=rnorm(I*J)

  b=c(rep(letters[c(1:I)],each=J))

  q=data.frame(a,b)

  test.factors=q[,2]

  aov1=aov(q[,1]~test.factors)

  summary(aov1)

  multicom=TukeyHSD(aov1,"test.factors")

  return(list(summary(aov1),multicom,plot(multicom)))}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the question difficult to understand, but could this code help please?

```
l1 <- c(-1, 2, -3, -4)
u1 <- c(2, 3, 1, 5)

l2 <- c(4,-2, -1, -6)
u2 <- c(5, -1, 4, 7)

l1 < 0 & u1 > 0 & l2 < 0 & u2 > 0
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
sum(l1 < 0 & u1 > 0 & l2 < 0 & u2 > 0)
# [1] 2
```